# Thumbnail Image and JPG

Tags: image, image-processing, jpeg, thumbnails

First I'll start with my assumptions about thumbnail:

1. Thumbnail is the same image reduced by size so it is smaller in size and faster to load
2. In Exif data there is referance to Thumbnail Image so it might be part of the jpg file

[image: Exif Tool]

Now what I think is that theoretically I can "inject" to a jpg file another thumbnail so that in windows i will see a small picture and when I will open the file I will see other picture

And my question is in guidlines how do I do that?

Thanks!

[image: Results I want]

Answer (score 1):

Some JPEG file format support including a thumbnail as part of the image header. In the JFIF format, the thumbnail can be either an RGB bitmap or a nested JPEG stream.

You need a JPEG encoder that will insert a thumbnail into the JPEG header. It's that simple. ImageMagic will do it. Many other JPEG encoders will do it as well.

Comment: Thanks. and if I want to do it programming (for example with python) you have any direction?

Comment: Take a look at the JFIF or EXIF standards. JFIF is simpler. You would need to filter the existing JPEG stream and insert a new APPn header, as described in the format specifications.